# MySQL: error in SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I'm attempting to gather/select data from a MySQL table to check it against new data in a cSV file and then update it.  I'm stuck on the selecting the data portion of the script.

Here's the error message:

> Error at line 44 in /home/atkelect/public_html/test/ap/import_list.php
>   1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FROM products WHERE products_model = 'A040503'' at line 1

```
SELECT products_id, list_price, FROM products WHERE products_model = 'A040503'
```

[TEP STOP]

Here's line 44:

```
  $product_query = tep_db_query("SELECT products_id, list_price, FROM ".TABLE_PRODUCTS." WHERE     products_model = '".tep_db_input($line[0])."'");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the Comma after list_price, should be like this

```
SELECT products_id, list_price FROM...
```

Comment: Thank you so much. something so small as always.  Sorry to bother you!